How much faster are the different heights of party members?
Was going to post an updated answer for:
What is the fastest way to move in Genshin Impact?
Because the current best answer doesn't involve "The First Great Magic" bow which gives "Movement SPD will be increased by 12%/15%/18%." To the wielder in the worst, better, best case for parties that can trigger it.
But since there's no Tall Anemo Bowmen that have a Speed Up / Stamina Cost Reduction passive, so the best use of a slot is probably Chasca, a Tall Anemo Bowwoman that has the other requirements...
However, I could be wrong, depending on how much faster a Tall Man is compared to a Tall Woman, vs the other three types (Medium Man / Woman, Short Girl). But I don't know those numbers, so I'm asking.
